# Is there a good tf2 tutorial?

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, tutorial, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Trying to use tf2 with hydro here, however I just can't get the tutorials to work. For the broadcaster, the C++ tutorial is missing. For the listener, there is a structure that seems to be inexistant : tf2_ros::PoseStamped; and the broadcaster uses another structure geometry_msgs::TransformStamped. The listener tells me there it doesn't have a lookupTransform method.

I think the existing tutorials are outdated, so any help in understanding how to use tf2 : listeners, broadcasters and data types, would be appreciated.

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109206/is-there-a-good-tf2-tutorial-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf2 tutorials have been updated.

https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/21

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1